# iPhone openGL error : ERROR: 0:1: '<' : syntax error syntax error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es

Hi Friends
I am new to openGLES, trying to work with HelloArrow program using shaders from a
 [Site](http://iphone-3d-programming.labs.oreilly.com/ch01.html)

but when i compiled i got the following error,


Source code 
[Download HelloArrow.zip](http://uploading.com/files/26c5a57a/HelloArrow.zip/)

```
ERROR: 0:1: '<' : syntax error syntax error
ERROR: Parser found no code to compile in source strings.
```

```
//  VERTEX SHADER
```

const char* SimpleVertexShader = STRINGIFY(
    attribute vec4 Position; 
    attribute vec4 SourceColor;
    varying vec4 DestinationColor; 
    uniform mat4 Projection; 
    uniform mat4 Modelview;

void main(void)
    {
        printf("fragment shader");
        DestinationColor = SourceColor; 
        gl_Position = Projection * Modelview * Position;
    }
);

```
//  FRAGMENT SHADER

const char* SimpleFragmentShader = STRINGIFY( 
    varying lowp vec4 DestinationColor;
    void main(void)
    {
    printf("fragment shader");
        gl_FragColor = DestinationColor;`
    } 
);
```

I don't have any idea.

Your suggestions are important to me so don't leave without a comment or answer

**[Sorry for my poor English]**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a very close look at this line:

```
 gl_FragColor = DestinationColor;`
```

the character behind the **;** should not be there

;-)

Comment: @fluchpunkt: Great!! its third time i'm posting the same question. only you answered. Great. Thanks a lot.